# scrapy: how to have a response parsed by multiple parser functions?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'd like to do something special to those each one of the landing urls in `start_urls`, and then the spider'd follow all the nextpages and crawl deeper. So my code's roughly like this:

```py
def init_parse(self, response):
    item = MyItem()

    # extract info from the landing url and populate item fields here...

    yield self.newly_parse(response)
    yield item
    return


parse_start_url = init_parse


def newly_parse(self, response):
    item = MyItem2()
    newly_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)

    # parse, return or yield items

    return item
```

The code won't work because spider only allows return item, request or None but I yield `self.newly_parse`, so how can I achieve this in scrapy?

#### My not so elegant solution:

put the `init_parse` function inside newly_parse and implement an `is_start_url` check in the beginning, if `response.url` is inside `start_urls`, we'll go through the init_parse procedure.

#### Another ugly solution

Separate out the code where `# parse, return or yield items` happens and make it a class method or generator, and call this method or generator both inside `init_parse` and `newly_parse`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to yield multiple items under `newly_parse` your line under `init_parse` should be:

```
for item in self.newly_parse(response):
    yield item
```

as `self.newly_parse` will return a generator which you will need to iterate through first as scrapy won't recognize it.